# How to delete unity default launchers

Tags: unity, launcher, bash

As a part of the system init script, I want to delete default launchers after blank ubuntu desktop installation using bash script. If I delete launchers from the `/usr/share/applications` it works, but then it deletes them for all users, while I want to delete them only for the active user. After blank install `~/.local/share/applications` don't exist.

Comment: "but then it deletes them for all users" why does this matter?

Comment: Well, it doesn't but, it just didn't feel right. There are bunch of launchers defined there, perhaps I might need some of those in the future, including those I want to remove now, like firefox. Also, I want to use such script in corporate environments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't delete the desktop files in `/usr/share/applications` because then you also can't start them using the dash. Instead unlock them all from the launcher.

First do a backup by

```
gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites > ~/.default_locked_launchers
```

Then remove them by

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites '[]'
```

This should unpin all applications for the current user. If you want to restore the original applications do

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites "$(cat ~/.default_locked_launchers)"
```

---

EDIT: you can do this for all users following the steps in [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27484/set-default-global-gnome-preferences-gnome-3) post.